# Definition of Derivatives

Tags: calculus

It is well known that $f(x) = |x|$ is not a differentiable function, because of $x = 0$. However, Wolfram gives the answer $\frac{x}{|x|}$ when asked for a derivative of $|x|$. This makes sense since $\frac{x}{|x|}$ is defined where $f$ is differentiable, except $x = 0$, but I don't understand how one can call this the derivative of $f$. Since $f$ is not differentiable itself, I think it is just impossible to talk about derivatives at that point.

Then, what is the exact definition of a derivative? I'm very confused.
(It seems possible when $f$ is defined as $x (x>0)$ and $-x(x<0)$, but it just seems weird differentiating $|x|$.)

Comment: the main thing is that we should not expect a computer algebra system to  report everything we might need to know.

Comment: The derivative exists everywhere except at $x=0$ and it is always given by that function.  Yes, one ought to make clear that the formula only applies to non-zero $x$.

Comment: $x/|x|$ is also the correct distributional derivative of $|x|$, in the sense that it makes integration by parts succeed, etc. The problem of pointwise value at $0$ has essentially no impact...

Comment: Wolfram is not the arbiter of mathematical correctness.

Comment: What's the derivative of $\tan{x}$? It's $\sec^2{x}$. That's not defined on any $\pi/2 + n\pi$ for any integer $n$, yet is it impossible to talk about derivatives at this point? No.

Comment: @Accelerator I think it's different from that, since $\tan x$ is a continuous function which is continuous on its domain, and also differentiable for all $x$ on its domain. However for my question $f$ is not differentiable for some point($0$) which is on its domain.

Comment: I believe the main reason is because we usually differentiate functions that are "differentiable for all $x$ on its domain". Some other cases involve the function being separately defined by the range of $x$, not a single function. I still do not know whether "differentiating $|x|$" is possible..

Comment: Differentiating $|x|$ is possible, just not at $0$. Just because a function is continuous everywhere on its domain doesn't mean it's differentiable everywhere on its domain.